# Unable to use Deep Learning RNN models trained on GPU instance, for the inference on CPU-only instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a deep learning model on GPU instance to speedup training process.
But unfortunately our product instances are CPU-only instances.
When I tried to use GPU trained model with CuDNNGRU on CPU-only instance, I got below error.

```
ValueError: CuDNNGRU is not compatible with GRU(reset_after=False)
```

similar kind of error you will get if you use CuDNNLSTMs

```
ValueError: CuDNNLSTM is not compatible with LSTM(reset_after=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using CuDNNGRU or CuDNNLSTM, use normal GRU or LSTM with following options

Code that throws error when CuDNNGRU or CuDNNLSTM models trained on GPU throw error while inference on CPU-only instances.

**CuDNNGRU**

```py
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    return tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(units, 
                                    return_sequences=True, 
                                    return_state=True,
                                    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
else:
    return tf.keras.layers.GRU(units,
                               return_sequences=True,
                               return_state=True, 
                               recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

*or*

**CuDNNLSTM**

```py
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    return tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(units, 
                                    return_sequences=True, 
                                    return_state=True,
                                    recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
else:
    return tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units,
                               return_sequences=True,
                               return_state=True, 
                               recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

Please use below code, so that you can use GPU trained models for the inference on CPU-only instances.

**GRU**

```py
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    return tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(units,
                                              return_sequences=True,
                                              return_state=True,
                                              recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
else:
    return tf.keras.layers.GRU(units, 
                               return_sequences=True,
                               return_state=True,
                               recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                               reset_after='True',
                               recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

*or*

**LSTM**

```py
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    return tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(units,
                                              return_sequences=True,
                                              return_state=True,
                                              recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
else:
    return tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units, 
                               return_sequences=True,
                               return_state=True,
                               recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                               reset_after='True',
                               recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

So by just using **reset_after=True** and **recurrent_activation='sigmoid'** options, my problem got solved.

Comment: It seems none of TF 2 versions have "reset_after" option in LSTM function.